# How to convert IPv6 link-local address to MAC address in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-conversion, ipv6, mac-address

I am looking for a way to convert a IPV6 address, for example

```
fe80::1d81:b870:163c:5845
```

into a MAC-Adress with Python. So the output should be

```
 1f:81:b8:3c:58:45
```

Like it is on this page: http://ben.akrin.com/?p=4103
How can I convert IPV6 to MAC?

Comment: The steps are documented at http://ben.akrin.com/?p=1347

Comment: RFC4941 makes this a bit useless.

Comment: That address, `fe80::1d81:b870:163c:5845`, is not an IPv6 address generated from a MAC address. An IPv6 address generated from a MAC address will have `ff:fe` in the middle of the Interface ID portion of the address, but that address has `70:16` there. What you have is an address using privacy extensions or random generation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are two functions to convert in both ways.

It might also be useful to check if the given arguments are correct MACs or IPv6s.

### From MAC to IPv6

```
def mac2ipv6(mac):
    # only accept MACs separated by a colon
    parts = mac.split(":")

    # modify parts to match IPv6 value
    parts.insert(3, "ff")
    parts.insert(4, "fe")
    parts[0] = "%x" % (int(parts[0], 16) ^ 2)

    # format output
    ipv6Parts = []
    for i in range(0, len(parts), 2):
        ipv6Parts.append("".join(parts[i:i+2]))
    ipv6 = "fe80::%s/64" % (":".join(ipv6Parts))
    return ipv6
```

### From IPv6 to MAC

```
def ipv62mac(ipv6):
    # remove subnet info if given
    subnetIndex = ipv6.find("/")
    if subnetIndex != -1:
        ipv6 = ipv6[:subnetIndex]

    ipv6Parts = ipv6.split(":")
    macParts = []
    for ipv6Part in ipv6Parts[-4:]:
        while len(ipv6Part) < 4:
            ipv6Part = "0" + ipv6Part
        macParts.append(ipv6Part[:2])
        macParts.append(ipv6Part[-2:])

    # modify parts to match MAC value
    macParts[0] = "%02x" % (int(macParts[0], 16) ^ 2)
    del macParts[4]
    del macParts[3]

    return ":".join(macParts)
```

### Example

```
ipv6 = mac2ipv6("52:74:f2:b1:a8:7f")
back2mac = ipv62mac(ipv6)
print "IPv6:", ipv6    # prints IPv6: fe80::5074:f2ff:feb1:a87f/64
print "MAC:", back2mac # prints MAC: 52:74:f2:b1:a8:7f
```